# Under what condition an element in the set of quadratic residues modulo a large prime is a generator

Tags: probability, number-theory

Let $p$ be a large prime. Given that $\gamma \in QR_p$, the set of all quadratic residue modulo $p$. Since $QR_p$ is cyclic so it has a generator. Under what condition $\gamma \in QR_p$ is a generator of $QR_p$ or what is the probability that $\gamma \in QR_p$ is generator?

If $p(=2p_1+1)$ is a safe prime then every $\gamma \in QR_p (\gamma \not\equiv 1\pmod p)$ is generator of $QR_p$. But if $p$ is not safe prime then $\gamma \in QR_p$ may not be a generator. For small prime $p$, we can check whether $\gamma \equiv g^2 \pmod p $ or not, where $g$ is primitive root modulo $p$. But without knowing primitive root modulo $p$, I could not proceed further. Is any one can suggest me how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$QR_p$ is a cyclic group of order $n=(p-1)/2$. The following recipe holds in all cyclic groups:

If $g\in C_n$ is a generator, then $g^k$ is another generator, iff $\gcd(k,n)=1$.

The previous fact implies that the number of generators is $\phi(n)$. The probability of a random element being a generator is thus $\phi(n)/n$.

To "quickly" test whether an element $x\in C_n$, is a generator you need to check that $x^{n/p_i}\neq1$ for all prime divisor $p_i\mid n$.

Both problems, calculating the probability and using the above test for whether an element is a generator, require you to know the prime factorization of $p-1$. This may be prove to be difficult.

Comment: We can at least estimate $\phi(p-1)$ based on a *partial* factorization $p-1=ab$ where $a$ has only primes $\le M$ (and $\phi(a)$ can be computed) and $b$ only primes $>M$. Then $b$ is divisible by at most $\lfloor \frac{\ln b}{\ln M}\rfloor$ primes and $\phi(b)>b\cdot \left(1-\frac 1M\right)^{\lfloor \frac{\ln b}{\ln M}\rfloor}$

Comment: Yes, @lulu: The $\phi(n)/n$ probability holds in any cyclic group of order $n$. Irrespective of what the group actually looks like.

Comment: Quite right, I misread the question.